# Javascript member variables enclosed with square brackets

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to debug an issue with Node.JS and Mongoose not saving the data correctly. I have a large object with multiple nested objects and arrays of objects. I'm viewing it in Chrome's devtools and the Node devtools right before saving. It's only a couple of nested objects that have this issue. The member variables in the array of objects are enclosed with square brackets []'s. I discovered this while viewing the data in Node devtools right before saving.

```
0: Object
    [attributeName]: "Grow raccoon tail"
    [componentId]: "58918f2c6f92704b0868aa30"
    [derivativeName]: ""
    [entityId]: "58918f9d6f92704b0868aa3e"
    [isStateVariable]: "false"
    [name]: "Feather"
    [parentId]: "0"
    [startValue]: "0"
    [variableName]: "tail"
```

Here is the schema of the problem object

```
var componentVariableSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    componentId: { type: ObjectId },
    entityId: { type: ObjectId },
    name: String,
    attributeName: String,
    isStateVariable: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    variableName: String,
    derivativeName: String,
    startValue: { type: Number, default: 0.0 }
},
{
    timestamps: true
});
```

Here is the schema of the parent object

```
var simulationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    createdDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    modifiedDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    name: { type: String, default: Date.now },
    description: { type: String },
    parentId: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Project' },

    // Variables
    componentVariables: [componentVariableSchema],
    simulationVariables: [simulationVariableSchema],

    // Integrator
    integratorType: { type: String },
    integratorParams: [Number],

    // Conditions
    startTime: 0,
    stopTime: 0,
    initialValues: [Number],

    // Containers for the code portion of the simulation
    initializationCode: { type: String },
    preFireCommandCode: { type: String },
    staveVariableDerivativesCode: { type: String },
    postFireCommandCode: { type: String },

    // A simulation can be run multiple times with different sets of results
    resultsList: [simulationResultSchema],

    createdByUserId: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    isViewableToOthers: Boolean,

    deletedBy: { type: ObjectId },
    deletedDate: { type: Date }
},
{
    timestamps: true
});
```

The simulationVariables array has the same problem. The parent object simulationSchema is within an array in it's parent object, but all of the member variables look correct. I've never seen this before, and I can't figure out what's causing it.

Comment: `that's what I have ...`, `that's what Chrome shows ...` ok, but what is your question?

Comment: I didn't get what is the problem you are facing? Are you getting wrong documents when fetched? Or are you getting documents saved in wrong format. Please specify the problem properly

Comment: My mistake, long day. The problem is the keys in the object are being surrounded by square brackets eg. `[isStateVariable]` instead of `isStateVariable`. When I go to save them in the database the names of the keys include the brackets. Other keys in the structure don't have the brackets.